# How to move columns if match length using sed or

Tags: awk, sed

I have the log file below:

```
1;127;20190529;094445;4261;7196
1;25;20190529;094636;1502;1536
1;1977;20190529;091419;7333;b001049109617002
1;1970;20190529;091426;b001049109617002;2138
1;1970;20190529;091426;b001049109617002;2139
```

I would like to check each line if the 5th column has `length > 4`, then move the column content to the end of the line and change the content of the first column from 1 to 3

I expected the output below:

```
1;127;20190529;094445;4261;7196
1;25;20190529;094636;1502;1536
1;1977;20190529;091419;7333;b001049109617002
3;1970;20190529;091426;2138;b001049109617002
3;1970;20190529;091426;2139;b001049109617002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One awk way:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} length($5) > 4 { $1 = 3; tmp = $5; $5 = $6; $6 = tmp } 1' inputfile
1;127;20190529;094445;4261;7196
1;25;20190529;094636;1502;1536
1;1977;20190529;091419;7333;b001049109617002
3;1970;20190529;091426;2138;b001049109617002
3;1970;20190529;091426;2139;b001049109617002
```

Though I think perl's array slices allow for a more elegant solution for setting/swapping fields:

```
$ perl -lF';' -e 'BEGIN{$,=";"} @F[0,4,5] = (3,@F[5,4]) if length $F[4] > 4; print @F' inputfile
1;127;20190529;094445;4261;7196
1;25;20190529;094636;1502;1536
1;1977;20190529;091419;7333;b001049109617002
3;1970;20190529;091426;2138;b001049109617002
3;1970;20190529;091426;2139;b001049109617002
```

Comment: this solution is correct and elegant, assuming the number of fields is 6.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'h;s/[^;]+/\n&\n/5;/\n.{,4}\n/{g;b};s/;\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2;\1/;s/[^;]+/3/' file
```

Make a copy of the original line. Isolate the 5th field and test its length. If it is 4 or less, revert to the original line. Otherwise use pattern matching to move the field to the end of the record and replace the value of the 1st field.

Comment: it doesn't work as expected, when the columns is moved, it loses the delimiter.

Comment: Oops! Missed out a `;` in the RHS of the substitution, corrected now.